Converting .py file to Databricks with Markdown
I wish to convert a python .py file into one that can be run on Databricks with multiple cells. I don't wish to do it in the GUI, as I'll eventually want an automated process for this. What is the minimal code to create a title cell and then have the rest of the code being Python code?
I've tried this, but it doesn't work:
%md
# Title

%python
# My code goes here

I could copy some output from a Databricks notebook I created my self I suppose, but it's really not that minimal.

If you want a notebook, you should start your Python file with the line
# Databricks notebook source

For a header, as well as for any other markdown you write in your notebook, start with the following right after the first line.
# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC ...put your text here...

Then, separate your cells with the following, including the empty lines before and after.

# COMMAND ----------


That's completely it. Any block of code that is Python code doesn't need the MAGIC command and doesn't need anything, as the code is Python by default due to your .py extension. This means that your exact case should be converted to the following:
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC # Title

# COMMAND ----------

print("Any Python code!")


Perfect. Any way to specify to the notebook that the code is explicitly Python? I'd like to also use R files as well, eventually

The way to specify is just with the file extension .py. So with an R file you would use .r. One thing to note is that the structure does depend a bit on the way that your default language handles comments. As R uses the same character for comments (#), the structure would be the same. However, if you are using SQL, then the top line, any magic command and the separator between lines would start with -- instead of #.

Much appreciated

Did you consider using the REST API from Databricks. Below is the link to the official documentation that might help. Using the API you can create and manage workbooks easily.
https://community.databricks.com/t5/community-platform-discussions/how-to-create-a-databricks-notebook-using-api/td-p/48411

The link is a forum post that appears to contain code that is someone's custom API for creating a Notebook. Unfortunately, it's missing the other end of the API, so I'm not able to use it, I'm afraid

I should mention, that an API would be a lot less clunky than weaving code in on the fly. Wish there was an official API for doing so. Thanks for the thought, @iinquisitiveTechie
